# bindfs startup with systemd

Tags: systemd, mount

My systemd startup scripts typically work quite fine, including mount-commands etc. Now I have added a line using bindfs

```
bindfs --map=1000/1001 /mnt/WrongPermissions/MyBook /mnt/share/MyBook
```

My startup-systemd-script "mystartup" is defined by

```
[Unit]
Description=My own startup skript

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mystartup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When using

```
sudo systemctl start mystartup
```

there is nothing mounted. The status of the service is given by

```
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting My own startup skript...
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mystartup.service: Child 8679 belongs to mystartup.service.
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mystartup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mystartup.service: Changed start -> stop-sigterm
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mystartup.service: Child 8681 belongs to mystartup.service.
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mystartup.service: cgroup is empty
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mystartup.service: Succeeded.
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mystartup.service: Changed stop-sigterm -> dead
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mystartup.service: Job 1185 mystartup.service/start finished, result=done
May 17 20:56:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started My own startup skript.
```

However, when using the bindfs command directly in the command line, the mount works properly. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Without `sudo` does it works?

Comment: @mattia.b89: The sudo does not change anything, so I removed it from the question. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try with **debug** switch?

Comment: @mattia.b89 Thanks for the idea. However, also with "systemd-analyze set-log-level debug", systemd just tells something like "everything right" (see new version of the question). I tried a source /etc/profile within the script and enabled a tty in the .service-file, but also not working.

Comment: I mean the one for *bindfs* command. See **man bindfs**

Comment: @mattia.b89: Ok, that kind of helped. the debug-flag of bindfs does not show any error, but it also sets bindfs to the foreground. Consequently, the startscript does not terminate but lives on like a background service. As long as it runs, the file-system is mounted. If I stop the script via "systemctl stop", the mount gets unmounted. I am a bit confused about this behaviour, since the typical terminated bindfs-command via a command-shell permanently mounts, even if I log-out from the system. But I think this shows, that bindfs can not be used via systemd. Thank you very much!!

Comment: In that case, try changing Type=oneshot to Type=forking

Comment: @meuh You are right! I tried it with "RemainAfterExit=true", but that worked. Thank you both so much!!!

Comment: Why not use "/source /destination none defaults,bind 0 0" in fstab?